# Как изменить цвет бордера в radio css

Tags: css, scss, radio

нужно поменять цвет бордера у всех элементов radio

```
<input type="radio" class="calc__block-glazing-input" />
```

Вот на такое надо поменять
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А было такое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надеюсь это вам поможет:

```css
.calc__block-glazing-input {
  border: 2px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #0060DF;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
}

#yes {
  border: 2px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #0060DF;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
}

#yes:checked {
  background-color: #0060DF;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="calc__block-glazing-input" />Ваш случай<Br>

<input id="yes" type="radio" checked="checked" ><label for="yes">Дополнение с label</label>
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68003309

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!